# On the fly XHTML validation (PHP output)

Tags: php, validation, xhtml

Given I have a php script of arbitrary complexity, running on an apache2 webserver, and I want to check that this script outputs only valid xhtml.

One way to achieve this that occurred to me was validating the output of this php script IN the script every time it is run, and storing generated errors and warnings in a mysql database.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I guess the main problem here is getting the output of the current script without rewriting every `echo` call.

**EDIT2:** I'd prefer the w3c sgml validation over html tidy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not only check but also fix common errors using [tidy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.tidy.php)

Example from http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.parsestring.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>

<html>
  <head>
   <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <p>error<br>another line</i>
  </body>
</html>

<?php

$buffer = ob_get_clean();
$config = array('indent' => TRUE,
                'output-xhtml' => TRUE,
                'wrap' => 200);

$tidy = tidy_parse_string($buffer, $config, 'UTF8');

$tidy->cleanRepair();
echo $tidy;
?>
```

This will output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>
      test
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      error<br />
      another line
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that's nice, but I'd rather use the w3c sgml parser instead of tidy. But this already helped me a lot, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course is that possible. You have to search for a program or service which validates for you the XHTML markup.

The problem is actually the speed and performance of your app. You definitely have to cache the outputs!

Comment: could you please be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 0):

This class will let you [validate output for proper HTML5](https://404it.no/en/blog/php_class_for_validating_html5). You don't want to do this runtime, as it would slow down your execution time. In stead, create a set of tests you can run before you deploy the website. I personally prefer [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/) as test framework.